# Text/Icons overlapping other content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap  button that will expand/show an unordered list. The children of the unordered list are rendering behind content beneath it as shown below.

[image]

The only portion that has a z-index defined is the dropdown-menu class:

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block" role="menu" aria-labelledby="591357bd3b522" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
                                        <li role="presentation" class="tigo-green widget-style" data-parent="591357bd3b522" data-style="tigo-green" data-style-name="green">
                        <span role="menuitem">green</span></li>
                                            <li role="presentation" class="tigo-blue widget-style" data-parent="591357bd3b522" data-style="tigo-blue" data-style-name="blue">
                        <span role="menuitem">blue</span></li>
                                            <li role="presentation" class="tigo-orange widget-style" data-parent="591357bd3b522" data-style="tigo-orange" data-style-name="orange">
                        <span role="menuitem">orange</span></li>
                                            <li role="presentation" class="tigo-red widget-style" data-parent="591357bd3b522" data-style="tigo-red" data-style-name="red">
                        <span role="menuitem">red</span></li>
                                            <li role="presentation" class="tigo-purple widget-style" data-parent="591357bd3b522" data-style="tigo-purple" data-style-name="purple">
                        <span role="menuitem">purple</span></li>
                                            <li role="presentation" class="tigo-brown widget-style" data-parent="591357bd3b522" data-style="tigo-brown" data-style-name="brown">
                        <span role="menuitem">brown</span></li>
                                            <li role="presentation" class="tigo-pink widget-style" data-parent="591357bd3b522" data-style="tigo-pink" data-style-name="pink">
                        <span role="menuitem">pink</span></li>
                                            <li role="presentation" class="tigo-grey widget-style" data-parent="591357bd3b522" data-style="tigo-grey" data-style-name="grey">
                        <span role="menuitem">grey</span></li>
                                            <li role="presentation" class="tigo-gold widget-style" data-parent="591357bd3b522" data-style="tigo-gold" data-style-name="gold">
                        <span role="menuitem">gold</span></li>
                                            <li role="presentation" class="tigo-lightblue widget-style" data-parent="591357bd3b522" data-style="tigo-lightblue" data-style-name="lightblue">
                        <span role="menuitem">lightblue</span></li>
                                    </ul>
```

Which is the default bootstrap dropdown, slightly modified by replacing the inner A element with a span and adding the background coloring.

What could possibly cause this? I've tweaked tons of the HTML/CSS and can not get this to budge.

Comment: If you have changed any classes related to bootstrap it loses its responsive behaviour.

Comment: I added a unmodified bootstrap select and it has the same issue.

Comment: What I see is that there are some classes that do not belong to bootstrap that's why I asked.

Comment: @Illuminati Please include any custom CSS you're using.

Comment: I changed the a element to a span and added background-color / color class. Nothing else is changed regarding generic bootstrap that I know of. Someone else on our dev team might have changed something.